# understanding how to rotate a matrix 90 degrees

Tags: java

I am try to understand the basic logic here, for example, what does 'n' represent ?
If you could give a brief explanation of how this works, that would be great.
here is the code:

```
public static void rotate(int[][] matrix, int n) {
    for (int layer = 0; layer < n / 2; ++layer) {
        int first = layer;
        int last = n - 1 - layer;
        for(int i = first; i < last; ++i) {
            int offset = i - first;
            int top = matrix[first][i]; // save top

            // left -> top
            matrix[first][i] = matrix[last-offset][first];          

            // bottom -> left
            matrix[last-offset][first] = matrix[last][last - offset]; 

            // right -> bottom
            matrix[last][last - offset] = matrix[i][last]; 

            // top -> right
            matrix[i][last] = top; // right <- saved top
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `n` is the size of the quadratic matrix.

Comment: What android has to do with this ?

Comment: is n the size of the columns or the rows ?

Comment: Both rows and columns. It's quadratic (square-shaped)

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm moves the elements, taking the outer elements first, the going inside.

Take this matrix (`n`=4):

```
A  B  C  D
E  F  G  H
I  J  K  L
M  N  O  P
```

First, you rotate the outer elements:

```
A -> D -> P -> M -> A
B -> H -> O -> I -> B
C -> L -> N -> E -> B
```

Then, you go to the inner loop, there is one position left there:

```
F -> G -> K -> J -> F
```

The actual rotation is using a temporary variable to save the first element. Let's say this one: `A -> D -> P -> M -> A`

The `A` value is saved to the variable `top`. Then `M` overwrites `A`, then `P` overwrites `M`, then `D` overwrites `P`, finally the `top` value is used to overwrite `D`,